# How can I detect if it's submit from new or edit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This before_filter validates before update or create record if captcha is correct.
When it's incorrect, it takes me back to previous page but all of the input data will be gone....
How can I remain the input data that was typed in at previous page?

I'd like to use before_filter and apply these 2 actions 'update' and 'create'. 
It should detect where the submit is come from and switches where to re-render 'new' or 'edit'

```
before_filter :simple_captcha_check, :only => [:update, :create] 

def simple_captcha_check
    if !simple_captcha_valid?
        flash[:error] = 'Wrong Captcha!'
        redirect_to :back
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're creating/updating an `User` model, your code can look like this:

```
def simple_captcha_check
  if !simple_captcha_valid?
    flash[:error] = 'Wrong Captcha!'

    if request.put? # We came from an edit request
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @user.attributes = params[:user]
      render :action => :edit
    elsif request.post? # We came from a new request
      @user = User.new params[:user]
      render :action => :new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: As it already worked, but for good practice you should use standard actions for the record mapping like, def update (with put) for record update and def create (with post) for new record creation. This will simplify your code and eliminate the conditional statements.